# Iteration of this rational function.

Tags: complex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Let $f:\mathbb{CP}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^1$ be defined by 
$$f\left(\left[x:y\right]\right)=\left[x\left(cx+dy\right):y\left(ax+by\right)\right]$$
or in affine form 
$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{x\left(a+bx\right)}{\left(c+dx\right)}$$
where $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{C}$ satisfy $ad-bc\neq 0$.

When do the iterates $f^k\left(x\right)$ converge? There are generally 3 fixed points: for a given fixed point $x_\ast\in \mathbb{CP}^1$ which initial $x\in \mathbb{CP}^1$ converge to $x_\ast$?

The fixed points are $\left[0:1\right],\left[1:0\right],\left[d-b:a-c\right]$.

I know that the superficially similar problem of iterates of Mobius transformations is easily solved.

Bonus: what changes if we move to $\mathbb{RP}^1$?

Comment: What is $\mathbb C \mathbb P^1$, sorry?

Comment: The projective line.